# php access object within object

Tags: php, oop, variables, object, foreach

I have an object in PHP and I'm using a

```
foreach ($items as $item)
```

to iterate through the items. However, $item contains another object called $item, which contains the $type variable whose value I need to access. How can I access the value of $type? What I want to do is:

```
foreach($items as item){
     if($item->item->type == 'this'){
             //do this
     } elseif ($item->item->type == 'that'){
             //do that
     }
}
```

But $item->item->type isn't picking up that value. How can I access it and use it for my function?

Comment: I dunno if it's relevant to anything other than your sample, but in your sample code 'item' in the foreach statement is missing the $ that should precede it.

Answer (score 2):

have you tired:

```
foreach($items as item){
     if($item->type == 'this'){
             //do this
     } elseif ($item->type == 'that'){
             //do that
     }
}
```

or you can debug your code to find out what is going on:

```
foreach($items as item){
     print_r($item);
}
```

and then you can see what kind of childs this $item has.